# React hooks: callback as prop re-render every hooks depending on it when it's called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

In the example below, I'm getting in a loop when I call the `onError` prop in `fetchItems()`. I don't understand why, when called, it triggers hooks depending on it. How can I fix this? Thanks!

```
const Component = ({onError}) => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const itemsRef = useRef(items);

  const fetchItems = useCallback(() => {
    const [first] = itemsRef.current;
    fetchNewItemsSince(first || 0).then((newItems) => {
      setItems((oldItems) => [...oldItems, ...newItems]);
    }).catch(onError);
  }, [onError]);

  // Update ref to dispose closure on `items` state
  useEffect(() => {
    itemsRef.current = items;
  }, [items]);

  // Call once on mount
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchItems();
  }, [fetchItems]);

  // Make an interval
  useEffect(() => {
    const id = setInterval(fetchItems, ONE_MINUTE);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(id);
    };
  }, [fetchItems]);
};
```

Comment: How is this `onError` implemented? Probably its call is making the parent re-render and therefore `Component` re-renders

Comment: I think you nailed the issue. Sinon the onError is changing a state in the parent, it re-render. I have to think of a way to change the architecture of my code.

Comment: Everything that you pass into an array in useCallback will behave as in useEffect. This makes the effect go into loop. Try removing it from the useCallback.

Comment: @twboc I can't remove it since it's an external dependency.

Comment: so try replacing the [onError] with a dummy placeholder [{}] and remove the catch statement

Comment: But how do I catch my error then?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the initial state with a function

Const [foo, setFoo] = useState(() => ‘foo’)

Your useCallback for that state instance probably runs once, correct me if I’m wrong, so if you set a function for useState it will only run once, consider is a component did mount but no update.

Maybe this is practice but I have never called something like [onError]  without setting an error state, because that’s what I think recognizes it.

So React is this great thing that renders certain components etc. UseEffect is great, I personally don’t use it to change the state, that for me is usually done in the JSX.

I would do like a onClick handler with the UseState method and watch for changes there. Instead your running a function that runs a setState event and watches for an event.

Let me know if that works or not if you need any explanation.

Comment: I tried `useState(() => [])` but it does not work.

I don't really understand what approach you're suggesting; I don't see from where else I could trigger the `setState()` but from a `useEffect()`. Could you give me an example based on the purpose of the example I gave? Thanks! :-)

Comment: Now I know why it's re-rendering: it's because that callback change a stage in the parent component so it re-renders. I am doing it all wrong...

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comments, `onError` is triggering a re-render on the parent and therefore the children will also render again.

Someone suggested removing `onError` from the `useCallback` array of dependencies. Although it might work, it is considered a bad practice because can lead to memory-leak. Have you tried to remove the `useCallback` wrap around your function?

Comment: I can't remove the `useCallback`, else I get a `Hook.eslintreact-hooks/exhaustive-deps` lint error.